# Can we deploy asp.net web application as AWS lambda function ( as container image )

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-containers

Recently AWS announced container support on lambda. i.e. Lambda function as a container image, where we can deploy a limited-sized containerized application to AWS lambda.

So I created containerized asp.net core razor pages web application and deployed that docker image to AWS lambda but I couldn't get it working.

My question is, can we even do that?

I know we can deploy console apps or web APIs according to this - [AWS Post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/net-5-aws-lambda-support-with-container-images/)  but I did not find anything on the internet about deploying a Website/Web application.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can deploy asp.net core web app in Lambda function. Check below blog post

[Serverless ASP.NET Core 2.0 Applications](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/serverless-asp-net-core-2-0-applications/)

I tried for a sample application from Visual Studio 2017 and it is working good.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Pankaj . Actually I am aware of this method but what I am looking for is hosting web app container inside lambda using recently announced AWS lambda - container support - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-container-image-support/